# Import hashed user passwords into Meteor app

Tags: passwords, meteor

I have an existing site that has user passwords hashed using sha1 hashing algorithm. I need to port those users (and passwords) to the new Meteor site.

Is this possible?

Comment: SHA1 isn't encryption. It's a (relatively weak) hashing algorithm.

Comment: It also looks like meteor salts them so it might not be that easy and uses SHA2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recently encountered a similiar problem and just migrated the accounts and had users reset their passwords.  you can then use the built standard accounts methods to handle login+reset functions.

login method call:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err){
  if (err){
    if(err.reason === "User has no password set"){
      Session.set('loginErrorMessage', 'you have been migrated... reset your password...');
      //your template does something with this to push user to reset their password
    }
  }else{
     //normal login     
  }
});
```

can only really do this if you have a custom login form, you could possibly just lightly customize the accounts-ui package if desired

this approach has worked pretty well for my app so far, users just have to follow the password reset procedure and they are good to go